# How do you select under emacs the key you sign/encrypt with when using mml?

Tags: mu4e, security, encryption

Long time `mutt` user, I am currently trying to learn how to deal with my mail from within emacs with the help of `mu4e`.

When it comes to signing mail, I use the following

```
(add-hook 'message-send-hook 'mml-secure-message-sign-pgpmime)
```

which automatically gets the job done.

As I have to manage several different keys / accounts, I am looking for the way to select the key I'll use for signing the message (`epa-list-keys` gives me three answers).

How do you select under emacs the key you sign/encrypt with when using `mml` ?

Answer (score 4):

We can set

```
(setq mm-sign-option 'guided)
```

and now we will be prompted with key selection menu before sending a message.

As [described](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Security.html):

> mm-sign-option -
>       Option of creating signed parts. nil, use default signing keys; **guided**, ask user to select signing keys from the menu.

We should be able to automate key selection based on e.g. *From:* field with help of

- [Default Encryption](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DefaultEncrypt)

  > DefaultEncrypt aims for automatic insertion of an MML secure encryption tags into messages if public keys (either GnuPG public keys or S/MIME certificates) for all recipients are available. In addition, before a message is sent, the user is asked whether plaintext should really be sent unencryptedly when public keys for all recipients are available.
- [*Keyfile* field](http://www.gnus.org/manual/emacs-mime_11.html) text auto-insertion

  > ‘keyfile’ - File containing key and certificate for signer.

but I have never been annoyed enough to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but no luck by now. I'll keep on trying.

Answer (score 0):

See: `mml-secure-openpgp-sign-with-sender`

> If `t`, use message sender to find an OpenPGP key to sign with.

This set the key to match the `From:` for me.  You can customize that variable too (and turn off the guided mode).